# When happens when line discipline receive_buf2() doesn't process all the offered data

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, tty

When incoming data arrives on a TTY with a line discipline, the line discipline callback receive_buf2() is invoked to process the data. This function is meant to return the number of bytes it actually consumed. If it does not consume them all, then when will the callback be invoked again? For example, will it only be invoked again when additional incoming data is received?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is a little late, but here it is:

According to the Kernel documentation found at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/serial/tty.txt

```
Driver Side Interfaces :

receive_buf() - (optional)Called by the low - level driver to hand
a buffer of received bytes to the ldisc for
processing.The number of bytes is guaranteed not
to exceed the current value of tty->receive_room.
**All bytes must be processed.**
```

All bytes from `receive_buf()` must be processed.